CWE 201: fetch function in react js
I'm getting Veracode vulnerability in fetch. Even though bwcc/name is part of my endpoint. But still its showing the URL having some data leakage. But i'm not sharing any sesnitive information over url.
  fetch("https://<domain_name>/bwcc/name", {
method: "GET",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": '<BEARER_TOKEN>',
},

})
Getting veracode alert in this line: fetch("https://<domain_name>/bwcc/name", {
What is the solution to suppress this vulnerability

https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/201.html CWE-201: Insertion of Sensitive Information Into Sent Data.
Maybe it's balking at "Authorization": '<BEARER_TOKEN>',

But vulnerability getting in the URL
fetch("https://<domain_name>/bwcc/name", {

Instead of using fetch, i've used axios. This will resolve the issue. After using axios, veracode scan not raised the vulnerability in API call
